# create new columns recursively in a list

Tags: r, list

I have the following vector:

```
x<-c("x1","x2")
```

Suppose I have the following list with two dataframes:

list(df1,df2)

where `df1` and `df2` are two different dataframes

what I want to do is to create a new column in each of these dafarames within this list that takes recursively the values of vector `x`

```
OLD list <- list(df1,df2)
```

After manual manipulations:

```
df1$var<- x[1]
df2$var<- x[2]
```

so my new list

```
Newlist<-list(df1,df2)
```

This is what I tried:

```
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  old.list[[i]]$var<-x[i]
}

new.list<-old.list
```

But, is there any efficient code considering that my `x` vector is very large in my case.

Comment: Try `Map(function(a,b) {a$var<-b;a},OLDlist,x)`.

Comment: To add above, look into `?mapply` (or its wrapper, `Map`) which iterates elementwise between equal length (or multiple-length) objects.